# make / gcc: What are possible causes of a "bad build"?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cmake

I have some unit tests which are failing due to some mathematical calculations returning unexpected results.

- The code itself is known to be correct.
- The build system hasn't changed
- The compiler flags haven't changed

We use cmake to generate our makefiles, which gives me a high level of confidence that the makefiles are correct.

The build has been working for many months, and it is just this particular, out of the ordinary, spurious failure, hence this question.

I looked at the object file for the failing test, and, as expected, it is newer than the source file, so make doesn't think it needs to rebuild it.

```
-rw------- 1 steve steve 64578    Feb  7 11:13 foo_tests.cc
-rw------- 1 steve steve 12930760 Feb 14 13:18 foo_tests.cc.o
```

If I delete the object file and rebuild, the tests now pass.

```
-rw------- 1 steve steve 12931080 Feb 16 13:57 foo_tests.cc.o
```

I have noticed the new object file is slightly larger. That is slightly puzzling.

- What can cause a bad build like this?
- Is there anything I can do to detect a bad build prior to running it and finding spurious errors?

**Build details:**

This is a release-mode binary with makefiles generated using cmake, and built using gcc 5.2.1 on Centos 7.2

The compiler flags we use are:

```
CXX_FLAGS
-Werror
-Wall
-Wextra
-m64
-msse2
-msse4.2
-mfpmath=sse
-ftemplate-depth-128
-Wno-unused-parameter
-Wno-maybe-uninitialized
-Wno-strict-aliasing
-pthread
-DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG
-ggdb2
-DNDEBUG
-O3
-funroll-loops
-fdevirtualize
-finline-functions
-fno-builtin-malloc
-fno-builtin-calloc
-fno-builtin-realloc
-fno-builtin-free

LINKER_FLAGS:
-m64
-rdynamic
```

Comment: _"Is there anything I can do to detect a bad build prior to running it and finding spurious errors?"_ Some build systems allow to do _dry runs_.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  There are too many things that can cause a build to break.

Comment: Maybe some header file that the `.cc` file uses changed, but your makefile doesn't list the header file as a prerequisite for the `.o` file.  Maybe the timestamp on your source file was incorrectly reset to some older value, or the timestamp on the `.o` file was incorrectly updated without rebuilding it.  Without seeing your makefile and/or knowing more about your setup it's impossible to say.

Comment: @MadScientist we use cmake, and the dependencies are listed correctly, I'm pretty sure. The build has been working for months with no changes to the CMakeLists, it is just this particular, out of the ordinary, spurious failure, hence the question

Comment: Then the most likely culprit is someone messing up the timestamps on your files somehow.  Alternatively there's an issue in the makefiles generated by CMake which seems unlikely unless you have a complicated setup where you are generating source or header files.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the comments. I'm at a bit of a loss, but no doubt the issue is in my CMakeLists somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you're right, it is too broad. I'm at a bit of a loss as to what could cause this to happen, as I though I understood cmake and make sufficiently to create correct CMakeLists etc, and the build has been working for months - this particular one seems to be spurious. The issue is no doubt in my CMakeLists though. I hoped that perhaps there was something else I wasn't aware of, hence the question. Looks like this isn't immediately the case. I'll add my vote to close.

Comment: @arrowd how would you debug a build which works for months, then with no change that I'm aware of spuriously creates a binary which can be run but produces incorrect results, and then rebuilding it works again? Regardless though, as mentioned in another comment, I'm in agreement with Thomas Matthews, and will add my vote to close

Comment: Have you tested that the "bad build" - the executable - fails to run always and on different computers? I would suspect some memory overwriting/initialization/alignment problems in the code itself. To find those I would use static code analyses and activate run-time checks. And you are using very sophisticated optimization options, which could reveal one or the other compiler bug (so you could try another compiler version). And since your project is CMake enabled you should try an other compiler e.g. from LLVM or Intel (and see what warnings they are coming up with).

Comment: Have updates been installed on this system since the previous build or during this build? Consider all files that are opened by a build - you could trace all of the 'open()' system calls if you wanted - that are never listed as dependencies in makefiles - e.g. the C compiler. If those change, your result may change.

Answer (score 1):

> - What can cause a bad build like this?

The most likely cause is bad source code, where "bad" can simply mean out of date.  If your makefile does not express *all* the dependencies of each target then it is possible that `make` fails to rebuild some components when they really need to be rebuilt.  The result can be a collection of object files that do not properly work together.

Another possibility is bad or inconsistent compiler options.  If the behavior of your program depends on compiler options (symbol definitions are a particularly likely culprit here), and you build components with the wrong options, then changing the options will not ordinarily be sufficient to persuade `make` to rebuild anything.  A clean build is the best policy in such a case.

Given that your "bad" build still produces objects that can be linked into a working (albeit incorrectly) program, and that removing the object file and rebuilding it with the same tool chain leads to a different object file with different behavior, I don't see any other likely options.

> - Is there anything I can do to detect a bad build prior to running it and finding spurious errors?

Supposing that the build in fact succeeds in the first place, no.  That's one of the things tests are *for*.  But note that performing a failing build is an entry point to producing a successful but bad build as a result of either of the kinds of issues I described.

Comment: I believe all the dependencies are listed correctly, as the build has been working for months without any change to the build system, compiler flags or other. We use cmake, which I would expect gets the dependencies correct when creating the targets and linking in dependencies etc. I have also noticed in the past when I change a compiler flag cmake causes all the affected targets to be considered out of date. It is just this particular, out of the ordinary, spurious failure, hence the question.

Comment: @SteveLorimer, for me, the bottom line is that the "bad" build produced an evidently valid object file, in the sense that it could be linked into a runnable executable that merely produces incorrect results.  There's no good way to detect a bad build of that sort except by testing it, since the runtime behavior of the code is the only thing indicating that there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. Very puzzling!